# How to create complex numpy array by skipping each column one by one

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an complex (3x6) numpy array like this:

```
x = [[(1+j2) ,(2+j8), (4+j1), (6+j8), (7+j3), (8+j2)],
     [(3+j8), (5+j1), (7+j5), (3+j2), (6+j1), (3+j1)],
     [(1+j5), (5+j4), (2+j9), (9+j5), (8+j1), (4+j1)]]
```

I want to split them as:

```
x1 = [[(1+j2), (4+j1), (7+j3)],
      [(3+j8), (7+j5), (6+j1)],
      [(1+j5), (2+j9), (8+j1)]]
```

and

```
x2 = [[(2+j8), (6+j8), (8+j2)],
      [(5+j1), (3+j2), (3+j1)),
      [(5+j4), (9+j5), (4+j1)]]
```

I mean, I want to get a new complex numpy array by skipping each column one by one.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using array indexing.

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array(
    [
        [(1 + 2j), (2 + 8j), (4 + 1j), (6 + 8j), (7 + 3j), (8 + 2j)],
        [(3 + 8j), (5 + 1j), (7 + 5j), (3 + 2j), (6 + 1j), (3 + 1j)],
        [(1 + 5j), (5 + 4j), (2 + 9j), (9 + 5j), (8 + 1j), (4 + 1j)],
    ]
)
x1 = x[:, ::2]
x2 = x[:, 1::2]
```

Yu can find a more detailed explanation of array indexing [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use [list comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html)

Exemple:

```py
x = [[(1+j2) ,(2+j8), (4+j1), (6+j8), (7+j3), (8+j2)],
     [(3+j8), (5+j1), (7+j5), (3+j2), (6+j1), (3+j1)],
     [(1+j5), (5+j4), (2+j9), (9+j5), (8+j1), (4+j1)]]

x1 = [ i[0:6:2] for i in x ]
x2 = [ i[1:6:2] for i in x ]
```